# Haskell Proxy Post request

Tags: haskell, proxy

I have following code working with proxy for a GET Request:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Network.Browser
import Network.HTTP
import Network.HTTP.Proxy (parseProxy)

main = do
  rsp <- browse $ do
    setProxy . fromJust $ parseProxy "127.0.0.1:8118"
    request $ getRequest "http://www.google.com"
  print $ rspBody <$> rsp
```

And this one for Post, but without proxy:

```
main = do
  r <- post "http://www.geocodeip.com" ["IP" := Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.pack "79.212.82.103"]
  html <- r ^. responseBody
  print html
```

But how to make a post request with proxy? I dont get it. please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple if you keep track of what you're doing.

We need to use `request` but feed it a POST request rather than a GET request. To make these we use `postRequestWithBody` which Hackage tells us has the parameters

```
postRequestWithBody :: String             | URL to POST to
                       -> String          | Content-Type of body
                       -> String          | The body of the request
                       -> Request_String  | The constructed request
```

So replace `request $ getRequest "http://www.google.com"` with:

```
request $ postRequestWithBody  "http://www.geocodeip.com/" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "IP=79.212.82.103"
```

...and you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks, works fine. But @CRDrost could you please also add a "fix" for https url's ? I found here an example hwo to use https: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html but i dont know how to implement this. thanks

Comment: I mean I think that's a separate question, but that library apparently starts with `requestTemplate = parseUrl "https://www.google.com/"` (or whatever) and then you would create a proxy (`{-# LANGUAGE: OverloadedStrings #-}` up top, then `myProxy = Proxy "127.0.0.1" 8118`), then you would set the request up by filling in the proxy using record syntax and the provided `urlEncodedBody` function, `request = urlEncodedBody [("IP", "79.212.82.103")] (requestTemplate{ proxy = Just myProxy })`. Then `newManager >>= http request` works for one query, or you'll use `do` to cache the manager.)